# Unit-testing with CakePhP - Cannot redeclare Mock CakeRequest Error

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.0

I`m trying to do unit-testing with CakePhP 2.3 and PHPUnit 3.7. I want to test the index function in my customer’s controller. In my controller I have:

```
public function index() {

$this->Customer->recursive = -1;
$data = $this->paginate('Customer', array( 'Customer.status'=>'active'));
$this->set('customers', $data);

}
```

I tried to follow the examples in book.cakephp.org, so I created fixture class in which I`m importing the Customer schema and all the records.

```
class CustomerFixture  extends CakeTestFixture{

  public $import = array('model' => 'Customer', 'records' => true);

}
```

And finally my test class looks like this:

```
class CustomersControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {

   public $fixtures = array('app.customer');

   public function testIndex() {

     $result = $this->testAction('/customers/index');
     debug($result);
   }
}
```

I have also $test variable added in database.php, which should work fine, because after I run the test I have all the records from customers table from the default database in my test database.

When I run my test I have the following error:

Error: Cannot redeclare Mock_CakeRequest_1de9f3b8::offsetUnset()

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution for this?